# Excel formula to stack two side-by-side cells in one cell

Tags: excel, spreadsheet, transpose

For example, if I have this,

[image]

Then I want to stack them in one cell.

[image]

Of course, I have hundreds of rows so I want to do it automatically. How can I achieve this? I know transpose, but that doesn't seem to do this.

Comment: You have several options for doing this, like cell merging. Or concat, it mostly depends on what you want to achieve.
The simplest of all is: assuming  the values in cells A1 and B1 and the result in C1
The formula in C1 will be
= A1 & " " & B1

Comment: It seems your solution does not seem to stack A1 and B1 (at least in my attempt)

Comment: You need `TEXTJOIN()` function. What is your excel version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by 'stack' you mean one above the other, try entering `=A1 & CHAR(10) & B1` in cell C1.

You might need to check the "Wrap text" in the cell formatting. For that, click-right on the cell, and in the appearing window, check this checkbox:

[image]

Comment: I was writing the same answer you were, when I saw it didn't work. Hence I looked for the issue and edited your answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

For small dataset you can manually concatenate cell like `=A1 & Char(10) & B1` but for large dataset you can use `TEXTJOIN()` function like below

```
=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),TRUE,A1:B1)
```

You must turn on `WRAP TEXT` for result cell to display line by line. Please note `TEXTJOIN()` is available on Office-2019 or higher. For older version you need UDF of textjoin.

[image]